# how to use Amazon S3 Uri links to download image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, uri

The scenario is, I got `s3://` type links to work with and i am supposed to write a script to download images from that links, I don't have much idea how to do it, tried reading some posts, docs did not help much, ended up with script which was throwing some exception which I did not understand, I used boto3 here.

So basically I got these kind links `s3://some-name-with-hyphens/other/and_one_more/some.jpg` I need write python script to download that object.

These images are hosted on public AWS S3 bucket.

Here is Script I used, I am showing here fake s3 uri:

```
import boto3
def find_bucket_key(s3_path):
    """
    This is a helper function that given an s3 path such that the path is of
    the form: bucket/key
    It will return the bucket and the key represented by the s3 path
    """
    s3_components = s3_path.split('/')
    bucket = s3_components[0]
    s3_key = ""
    if len(s3_components) > 1:
        s3_key = '/'.join(s3_components[1:])
    return bucket, s3_key


def split_s3_bucket_key(s3_path):
    """Split s3 path into bucket and key prefix.
    This will also handle the s3:// prefix.
    :return: Tuple of ('bucketname', 'keyname')
    """
    if s3_path.startswith('s3://'):
        s3_path = s3_path[5:]
    return find_bucket_key(s3_path)


client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name, key_name = split_s3_bucket_key(
    's3://some-name-with-hyphens/other/and_one_more/some.jpg')
response = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
```

And the exception I got:

```
File "C:\Users\BASAVARAJ\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 373, in add_auth
raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: Can you post the script and the error that you encountered as well?

Comment: which programming language you are using?

Comment: @Abhijit i was trying with python

Comment: @LRutten i have added the script and error now

Comment: @PO_ Are the S3 objects publicly accessible?

Comment: @PO_ you should provide credentials in an environment variable or in aws profile under <user_dir>/.aws/credentials

Comment: check this for more info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: @Nishit it is written that "The image archives for the competition are hosted on a public AWS S3 bucket in the following locations" and they provided links starts with S3://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have AWS credentials to perform the request, then you need to perform an unsigned request.  Replace the client creation with this to create a client that won't sign any requests:

```python
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.config import Config
client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: how to download image now

Comment: @PO_ if you have a different question, please open a new question with details on what you're asking.

Comment: sir here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303349/how-to-deserialize-botocore-response-streamingbody